# List all the pro's and con's of the most used Angular Test frameworks. Like Protractor, cypress, Nightwatch, Nightmare, webdriver.io, puppeteer

Tags: protractor, puppeteer, nightwatch.js, webdriver-io, cypress

I am looking for a pro/con list of popular angular e2e test frameworks. I am looking for a comprehensive and detailed list to help me decide upon a framework for my usage. Not looking for "the best framework" rather looking for a detailed breakup.

Comment: Google will help you out.

Comment: it did, only to an extent though :-)

Comment: Then you should add exactly what you're looking for. Firstly, this is a broad question and secondly, this question is bound to get opinionated answers.

Comment: I've edited the question if that helps. And yes, I am Ok with opinionated answers. Is there some link or article that you can redirect me to? I am just looking for a brief tabular column of pros/cons

Answer (score 0):

Still google is your friend.
There are multiple people who have investigated in subjects for the best e2e test framework for JavaScript applications:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/top-javascript-testing-frameworks-in-demand-for-2019-90c76e7777e9
https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/8oorxa/what_are_best_endtoend_testing_frameworks_these/
https://medium.com/welldone-software/an-overview-of-javascript-testing-in-2018-f68950900bc3

We had made the choice between Cypress and TestCafe and choose Cypress since it does more things 'magically' for you. That results in less need of programming skills.